# how to put quotes in directive template ng-class

Tags: angularjs

I have directive, in directive - template where I want to use ng-class, but I have a problem - too many quotes, so ng-class can't read the class. Example:
`template: "<div ng-class='{"btn-default":true"}'>Some</div>"` How can I make quotes for "btn-default", in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use \ with the qoutes to escape them and it will work

`template: "<div ng-class='{\"btn-default\":true}'>Some</div>"`